# Set width of UINavigationController loaded from storyboard

Tags: uiview, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I'm using ECSlidingViewController for an iPad app, i'm trying to get a UINavigationController as the master page (menu) that will be revealed under the left side of the main UIViewController.

To do this the UINavigationCOntroller needs a specific width otherwise it goes full width which isn't desired.

I'm using storyboards and load the viewControllers like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setup the view controllers
    self.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTop"];    
    self.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
}
```

How can I restrict the width of this to 320px? I know I have to set the frame, it's just where and how.

Comment: Can't you embed only the leftviewcontroller in the navigation controller?

Comment: Yes that is what i'm trying to do but to make it only 320px wide, it defaults to full width

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was actually quite easy once I had thought about it. I made sure that my menu viewcontroller was embeddedin a UINavigationController in the storyboard. Removed the storyboardID from the menu VC and added it to the UINavigationController.

Then I subclassed UINavigationController and added the following to the viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 

    [self.slidingViewController setAnchorRightRevealAmount:320.0f];
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftWidthLayout = ECFixedRevealWidth;

}
```

removing that code from the original menu VC viewDidLoad method. Reading the doc's for ECSlidingViewController adding ECFixedReveal will size the VC to match the setAnchorRightRevealAmount value.

Now I have a navigation controller within my revealed left menu.